# Beamer: Missing $ in frame

Tags: math-mode, beamer, errors

Trying to compile the following code in a `beamer` presentation:

```
\subsection{I servizi LBS oggi}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{La privacy negli odierni servizi LBS}
\begin{block}{Cosa ci dicono gli studi}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Gli utenti sono ormai sempre più sensibili alla privacy delle loro informazioni di posizione
    \item Il successo di un applicativo LBS è fortemente influenzato dalle modalità offerte all'utente di specificare le preferenze nella gestione dei propri dati sensibili (la propria posizione)
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{columns}[C]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Le tecniche utilizzate}
Attualmente:
\begin{itemize}
\item blacklist
\item profili
\item invisibilità on-the-fly (\textit{Hide me!})
\end{itemize}
Cosa manca?
\begin{itemize}
\item Regole di autorizzazione a carattere spazio-temporale \Rightarrow \textit{"I miei colleghi di lavoro mi possono vedere solo nei giorni e negli orari lavorativi e solo quando sono in ufficio"}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.99\columnwidth]{chiesa}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I'm getting the good ol' "Missing $ inserted" error in the `\end{frame}` line. I'm quite new to `beamer`: it could be related to the `column` commands? In every example I found columns are declared at the beginning of the frame, but I don't think it would be such a problem if I choose to put another block before them...anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `\Rightarrow` in math mode:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Regole di autorizzazione a carattere spazio-temporale $\Rightarrow$ \textit{"I miei colleghi di lavoro mi possono vedere solo nei giorni e negli orari lavorativi e solo quando sono in ufficio"}
\end{itemize}
```